# Draw animated circle for timer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a transparent 2d Texture of a circle that isn't full and has strokes and I want to change the pixels of this texture during run-time so that it looks like the circle is filling up with red.

I'm totally lost and confused about how to do this so can anyone help me please.

Also if someone could explain it with `C#` I'd be gratefull.

Comment: With Unity 4.6, you can create a UI Image, set the Image Type to Filled, and then choose between horizontal, vertical, and radial fills: http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/script-Image.html

Comment: Thank you this solved all of my problems